# Does CreateXpsDocumentWriter create an XPS or an OXPS document?

Tags: c#, xps, xps-generation

I [read](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/when-xps-not-xps-when-its-oxps) that the `XPS printer` in `Windows 8` produces `OpenXPS` (.oxps) files whereas its counterpart in earlier Windows versions produce `XPS` (.xps) files. So printing `XPS` files under `Windows 8` implies a compatibility issue. Fair enough. But, what type of file does the [CreateXpsDocumentWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.xps.packaging.xpsdocument.createxpsdocumentwriter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method create?

Does it use the XPS printer? If yes, how can you detect which XPS/OXPS setting the printer has? Or is it possible to choose XPS/OXPS via an API?

Comment: `what type of file does the CreateXpsDocumentWriter method create?` What do you get when you try this?

Comment: That's what I asked above. How can I know what it outputs? When I try this, I get an XPS... or it could be an OXPS. I can examine its contents, but I wouldn't know what to look for.

Comment: @admdrew is it possible that the OP has no Windows 8 at hand? Like many others too, so trying is not possible for everyone (like me). I also want to know what gets created

Comment: @Firo To be fair, l33t did say `When I try this`, so he/she probably has access to Win8.

Answer (score -1):

If the extension is oxps, chances are that you got an openxps. try renaming it to .zip. If it's openXPS, you will be able to view the contained parts.

According to the remarks in the [XpsDocument class description](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.xps.packaging.xpsdocument(v=vs.110).aspx), you will get XPS, not OpenXPS
("For more information about XPS see the XML Paper Specification (XPS) available for download at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=65761.")

Comment: Both `.OXPS` and `.XPS` are `.ZIP` containers.